# Установка Qgis на Ubuntu/Debian

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, qgis

Нужно поставить Qgis на Ubuntu. Есть [стандартная документация](http://www.qgis.org/ru/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#linux), но предлагаемые решения не работают. `apt-get` не обнаруживает некоторые необходимые пакеты и фейлится.

> В случае ошибок сервера ключей добавьте публичного ключ репозитория qgis.org в связку ключей apt, выполнив:
>
> ```
> wget -O - http://qgis.org/downloads/qgis-2015.gpg.key | gpg --import
> gpg --fingerprint 3FF5FFCAD71472C4
> gpg --export --armor 3FF5FFCAD71472C4 | sudo apt-key add -
> ```

Это тоже не помогло.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сработало через добавление отдельного PPA c unstable-релизом.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable

sudo apt-get update
```

Если нужно обновить:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Если установить:

```
sudo apt-get install qgis python-qgis qgis qgis-plugin-grass
```